# Can you get a USA visa and enter the country if you already have an Iranian visa in your passport

Tags: visas, usa, iran

I am a Serbian national, living in the Netherlands. I traveled to Iran for business once and thus have an Iranian visa in my passport. I will likely need to travel to USA for work as well. Will the Iranian visa/stamp be a problem?

Comment: The interviewer might ask a few more questions about that visit, but in general it won't affect. I am saying this because I know many people who been to Iran and they still got the visa.

Comment: Usually okay, but it does not always turn out well, as for [this guy](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/niels-gerson-lohman/us-border-crossing_b_4098130.html)